# Excel VBA If Cells(x,J). Value = value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to excel vba, but I'm looking to use an if then statement to input a value. Below is the function I'm attempting to use. It throws a compile error on the bolded lines. Basically I'm trying to replace cell Jx with cell AXx if Jx = N/A. Please help!

```
Public Function GetDivisionFromCustRef()

Sheet1.Select

Dim x As Integer

x = 1

Do Until x > 8

**If Cells(x, J).Value = "N/A"**
    **Then**
        Cells(x, J).Value = Cells(x, AX).Value
        x = x + 1        
    Else: Cells(x, J).Value = Cells(x, J)
End If
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: `Cells(x, "J")`.

Comment: change all `J` to `"J"` and make sure `Then` is on same line as `If`. And no need for `Else` statement in this case because you are only setting the value to itself (unless you want to hardcode a formula result).

Comment: You also don't need the Else clause. I would use a For-Next loop, but that might just be me.

Comment: Is the *value* "N/A" (i.e. a string), or is it actually a `#N/A` error value? If it's an actual error value, the code will blow up at run-time once the compile error is fixed, because an error value can't be coerced into any other data type to be compared against another value - in which case you'll need to use `If IsError(Cells(x, "J").Value Then` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`J` is a valid variable name. In VBA when you want something to be a *string literal*, you need to enclose it in double-quotes, so `"J"` - exactly like you did with `"N/A"` there.

If your module said `Option Explicit` at the top, that `J` would have caused a compile error for being an undeclared variable - which is a good thing! You should always specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, that way typos and undeclared variables will prevent compiling a program that can't possibly produce correct output.

The `If...Then` statement must have the `Then` token on the same line as the `If` keyword - there are two ways to write an `If` statement.

Inline:

```
If {condition} Then {statement}
```

Or block:

```
If {condition} Then
    {statements}
{Else}
    {statements}
End If
```

Note that the *instructions separator* token (`:`) is redundant after `Else`.

The procedure is a `Function`; functions normally *return a result* - something for the caller to consume. Given the name "get division from cust ref", I would be expecting the function to return something like a division code given a customer code, or similar. You can make a function return its result by assigning to its identifier:

```
GetDivisionFromCustRef = {result}
```

Functions don't normally have side-effects either, like selecting a sheet, or replacing cell values; you have a `Function` procedure, but you're using it like a `Sub`. Make it a `Sub` procedure instead, and name it after its purpose - it's not "getting" anything. Something like this:

```
Public Sub UpdateDivisionForCustomers()
```

`Sheet1` doesn't need to be selected or activated. Instead of working with unqualified `Cells` member calls, use this `Sheet1` object as a qualifier:

```
If Sheet1.Cells(...) ... Then
    Sheet1.Cells(...) = Sheet1.Cells(...)
End If
```

If typing repeatedly "sheet1" gets annoying, you can use a `With` block:

```
With Sheet1
    If .Cells(...) ... Then
        .Cells(...) = .Cells(...)
    End If
End With
```

Lastly, the string literal `"N/A"` is not a worksheet cell error value - it's a string literal that contains the characters `N`, `/`, and `A`. If you mean to verify whether a formula returned an `#N/A` error, you need to use the `IsError` function, because that cell's value will be of data type `Variant/Error`, and trying to compare that data type with anything other than an `Error` will throw run-time error 13 / "type mismatch".

---

Incorporating all of the above:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateDivisionForCustomers()

    Dim x As Integer        
    x = 1

    Do Until x > 8       
        If IsError(Sheet1.Cells(x, "J").Value) Then
            Sheet1.Cells(x, "J").Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "AX").Value
            x = x + 1
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(x, "J").Value = Sheet1.Cells(x, "J").Value
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to offer a speedier, perhaps more efficient, way to do this. I am assuming of course, that your cells hold formulas.

```
On Error Resume Next 'needed here in case there are no formula cells with errors
Dim errors As Range
Set errors = Range("J1:J8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
On Error GoTo 0 'be sure turn error catching back on 

If Not errors Is Nothing Then

    With errors
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[40]"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End If
```

And if you need to flatten the formulas for correct values as well, you can add this line after the other code execution:

```
With Range("J1:J8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
   .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: That's assuming `"N/A"` actually means to be a cell error value, i.e. `#N/A`. OP's code doesn't do that, as it stands `"N/A"` is a string literal, not a cell error - whether that's the actual intent, hasn't been clarified.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Yes. I noted that assumption in my edit. Still thought it was a valuable piece of code to offer even with the assumption. If I am way off, I will delete :)

Comment: It *is* valuable code (upvoted) - don't delete your answers! I'd probably just be more verbose about explaining `SpecialCells` and `FormulaR1C1` usage and even more about `On Error Resume Next / GoTo 0`, but I don't think it should be deleted even if the assumption is off.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I am off the assumption that anyone can google what they don't understand, considering there is so much information out there. That's why I leave off all the explanation. That is what I usually do anyway. I always appreciate the way you answer, too, because I often learn a lot from you - even things I as of yet don't fully understand :)